# Substring of two strings in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe

I have a string like  " How\Are\You-1 " . I need to substring till to " You-1 " with out using first and last index.

Thanks,
ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regular Expressions:

```
var myPattern:RegExp = /.+\\.+\\(.+)/;  
var str:String = "How\\Are\\You-1";
trace(str.replace(myPattern, "$1"));
```

Comment: -1. You forgot to escape the backslashes in the string, and to quote the replacement pattern. Also replacement should be with `"$1"` and not `"$&"`. The later means the whole match - which is the whole string. Please fix it and I'll remove the down vote

Comment: var myPattern:RegExp = /.+\\.+\\\(.+)/; var str:String = "How\\Are\\You-1"; var str1:String = str;  .If i like this, it will work..?

Comment: No need to assign it to another variable, the string `str` already is: `You-1`